# How do I prevent apt-get upgrade from installing unwanted packages

Tags: 12.04, apt

Package "gwibber" is not installed on my server, and yet when I run `apt-get upgrade` I see the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gwibber gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook gwibber-service-identica
  gwibber-service-twitter libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2 libneon27-gnutls
  libruby1.8 rsyslog
```

when I run `apt-get remove gwibber` I see:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package gwibber is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

How do I run get apt-get to **NOT** install things I don't want or need on upgrade requests?

**update**

The issue was that the services/libraries for *gwibber* were not removed removing `gwibber*` and `libgwibber` addressed the issue.

Comment: Install Synaptic and view these packages and send a screenshot of that. Alternatively, you could just replace command-line apt-get with synaptic.

Comment: Arpit, thanks, but the point of the question is not to install another package -- this is a server, and ideally it should not be running a window manager to begin with, and should have as few non-standard packages installed as possible.

Comment: @adam you must have to see your repositories and unable the repositories of 3rd party softwares and than try to update and upgrade

Comment: I just wanna see the output in visual form, so that we can see what's really happening.

Comment: I just wanted to see the problem in visual form. I'm sorry I'm not that familiar with the server platform. Anyways, I'm happy that the problem is solved. Btw, don't forget to mark this as solved.

Comment: If you solved the problem yourself, please do provide it as an answer, rather than adding it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the services/libraries for gwibber were not removed removing `gwibber*` and `libgwibber` addressed the issue.